# Session factory in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, factory

Session Factory is heavy weight object in hibernate so it is wrong to call heavy weight object frequently so how to use single object of session factory in whole project if anybody else have example then please share

Answer (score 1):

In a Spring context, expose the sessionFactory as a bean.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    final Properties properties = new Properties();

    final LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource()).scanPackages("yourPackageNameHere");

    builder.addProperties(properties);

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

The use the SessionFactory bean in another class

`@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;`